# Combine data from two XMLs using XLT2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a requirement where I need to combine the data from two queries and in the result of queries, there is a common field . Based on the matching  from both the result, I would like to produce the final XSLT.

Can this be achieved using XSLT2.0? If yes please help how to achieve this.

Data from 1st query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <accounts>
      <aid>123</aid>
      <aname>abc</aname>
      <contact>
         <cid>c124</cid>
         <cname>ankur</cname>
      </contact>
      <contact>
         <cid>c123</cid>
         <cname>amit</cname>
      </contact>
   </accounts>
   <accounts>
      <aid>456</aid>
      <aname>xyz</aname>
      <contact>
         <cid>c099</cid>
         <cname>jain</cname>
      </contact>
      <contact>
         <cid>c107</cid>
         <cname>vasim</cname>
      </contact>
   </accounts>
</data>
```

Data from 2nd query

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <record>
      <aid>123</aid>
      <role>role1</role>
   </record>
   <record>
      <aid>456</aid>
      <role>role2</role>
   </record>
   <record>
      <aid>458</aid>
      <role>role3</role>
   </record>
</data>
```

Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<final>
   <accounts>
      <aid>123</aid>
      <aname>abc</aname>
      <role>role1</role>
      <contact>
         <cid>c124</cid>
         <cname>ankur</cname>
      </contact>
      <contact>
         <cid>c123</cid>
         <cname>amit</cname>
      </contact>
   </accounts>
   <accounts>
      <aid>456</aid>
      <aname>xyz</aname>
      <role>role2</role>
      <contact>
         <cid>c099</cid>
         <cname>jain</cname>
      </contact>
      <contact>
         <cid>c107</cid>
         <cname>vasim</cname>
      </contact>
   </accounts>
</final>
```

Comment: "please help how to achieve this": you should show us your attempt and how it failed. Use any tutorial on grouping with `xsl:for-each-group group-by` to get started.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use a key and the key function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc('input-document2.xml')"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="role" match="record" use="aid"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="accounts">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="aid, aname, key('role', aid, $doc2)/role, contact"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzkTcP is an online sample where the second document is inlined for the self-containedness and completeness of the example but of course you can use the `doc` function to load from a file or a URI in general as shown above.